# Datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, formularios, datepicker, calendar

Estoy intentando hacer de un input un tipo calendario para seleccionar una fecha, pero en consola siempre me aparece el error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Este es el código que tengo para los scripts y el css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/displaytag.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/common.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- FontAwesome (iconos) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Quilljs -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```

Y este el jsp del formulario:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div>
        <label for="fechaInicio"><spring:message code="fechaInicio" /></label>  
        <form:input id="fechaInicio" path="fechaInicio" readonly="false" cssClass="form-control" required="required" /> 
        <br />  
        <form:errors cssClass="alert alert-danger medium" path="fechaInicio" /> 
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fechaInicio").datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

He de decir que estoy usando los tags de Spring para los formularios, pero con inputs normales he obtenido el mismo resultado

Answer (score 2):

Incluye la librería datepicker para utilizar sus funciones.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
```

Comment: Es el datepicker de jquery-ui, no de bootstrap. Se puede encontrar un ejemplo aquí [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

Ordene un poco tus **tags**, ya que como buena práctica se deben especificar los `scripts` al final del documento para evitar que nuestras páginas demoren en iniciarse debido a que el `DOM` se **carga de manera lineal** en nuestro navegador.

A mi me funcionó perfecto y con las mismas versiones que estas utilizando =)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fechaInicio").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group col-md-4 mt-5">
  <div>
      <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha</label>  
      <input type="text" id="fechaInicio"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```